# Smallest number in array quirk

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to solve a problem on CodeWars that has me finding the smallest number in an array. Here is my current code:

```
public class SmallestIntegerFinder {
public int findSmallestInt(int[] args){
    int smallest = args[0];
    for(int i=1; i < args.length; ++i){
        if(args[i] < args[0]){
            smallest = args[i];
        }
    }
    return smallest;
 }
}
```

Why doesn't this work? But when I change **args[0]** in the **if** statement to the variable **smallest** it works. What's the difference between the two? They both point to **args[0]** don't they?

```
public class SmallestIntegerFinder {
public int findSmallestInt(int[] args){
    int smallest = args[0];
    for(int i=1; i < args.length; ++i){
        if(args[i] < smallest){
            smallest = args[i];
        }
    }
    return smallest;
 }
}
```

The test array i'm using is: {78,56,232,12,11,43}

Answer (score 6):

Because `args[0]` is the first element in the array, while `smallest` *starts* with the first element; it updates to the next smallest value (consider 3, 1, 2; 2 is smaller than 3 but 1 is smaller than 2). You could also use [`Math.min(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min-int-int-) like

```
public int findSmallestInt(int[] args) {
    int smallest = args[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < args.length; ++i) {
        smallest = Math.min(smallest, args[i]);
    }
    return smallest;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Smallest gets assigned the value that was in args[0], it's not a pointer to that memory location.  Changing smallest does not change args[0].  So in your loop you are always comparing to args[0] instead of the lowest value you have seen so far.

Answer (score 2):

Its not the same,

1. In the first case, you are putting the smallest as args[i], but again comparing with args[0].
       So the base value for comparision is never updating.
2. In the second case, your base value is being updated to the current smallest value and you are comparing
       with that, and so you get the overall least value.

Answer (score 2):

Using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8).

```
public static int findSmallestInt(int[] args){
    return IntStream.of(args)
                    .min()
                    .getAsInt();
}
```

OR

```
public static int findSmallestInt(int[] args){
    return IntStream.of(args)
                    .min()
                    .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
}
```

Comment: out of curiosity :  in what condition will IllegalArgumentException could be thrown ?

Comment: `getAsInt()` will throw `NoSuchElementException` when `args` is empty, similar to your original code throwing `IllegalArgumentException` when `args` is empty. BTW, @LeTex, that is the condition that does it. In this case, `orElseThrow()` is better, since it clearly states the desired intent.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers have already explained to you why your code is (not) working: in the comparison `args[i] < args[0]`, you always compare to the first value of your array.

One remark: if you are using Java 8, there is a somewhat *more readable* solution:

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {78,56,232,12,11,43};
    int min     = IntStream.of(array).min().getAsInt();
    System.out.println("Minimum: "+min);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is copying the contents of `args[0]` into `smallest`. `arg[0]` and `smallest` are not the same memory locations.

In the first code block you are updating the contents of `smallest` if the `i`th value is less than the `0`th. Updating `smallest` will only update the value in that variable, **not** in `args[0]`

In the second code block you are both comparing, and updating, `smallest` with the values from `args[i]`.

---

You need to understand what happens when you write something like `int smallest`. This allocates a new portion of memory for that variable. Running the code `int smallest = 1` will put `1` in `smallest`.

If you have two different variables you will have two distinct memory locations, even if you write `smallest = largest`. All this does is copy the *contents* from `largest` into `smallest`.

This can be confusing when you have objects, rather than primitive types, being copied.
Obviously, in the case of primitives the value (for example `1`) is copied from one variable to another. You'd end up with the case where `smallest = 1` and `largest = 1`.
When it comes to objects it's a little different. In the case of `Object smallest = new Object()`, `smallest` would not contain an `Object` but rather the location that `Object` exists in memory. If you now do `largest = smallest` you would be copying the location, not the actual object.

If you're interested in this you can read more about it from one of my favourite answers on here: [Is Java “pass-by-reference” or “pass-by-value”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40523/5559221)

Answer (score 0):

It is because by doing `smallest = args[i];` you are updating the smallest value in `smallest` variable and not `args[0]`.

In your first solution you are comparing each and every value in the array with `args[0]` but if the value of any `i`th element is found smaller then you update the `smallest` variable instead of `args[0]`.

You should update `args[0]` if you want your first code snippet to work.

Here is the corrected code snippet:

```
public class SmallestIntegerFinder {
    public int findSmallestInt(int[] args) {
        int smallest = args[0];
        for(int i=1; i < args.length; ++i) {
            if(args[i] < args[0]){
                args[0] = args[i];
            }
        }
        return args[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: That updates the input, which is very likely not a good idea. But, if you really want to do this, remove variable `smallest` and return `args[0]`.

Comment: @Andreas I know. But the question is more about *"Why the first code is not working but second code is!"*

Comment: Well, your code is not working either, because you're returning `smallest`, which has the value `arg[0]` *initially* had, so you're not returning the smallest value, but the first value. In my opinion, you tried to fix the code by changing the wrong thing. Changing `args[0]` to `smallest` in the `if` statement would have worked too, and without modifying the input array.

Comment: @Andreas Either you haven't read the question properly or you misunderstood it completely. That's the whole point. OP wants to know why his first code is not working. He is doing the exactly same thing which you suggested in the second code. Thanks for highlighting the typo in the code though. I have fixed it. :)

Comment: No, the whole point of the question is what the difference is between using `args[0]` or `smallest` in the `if` statement. That is, in the *expression*, not the block. You are suggesting a totally different solution, which is to change the *block* to use `args[0]`, rather than changing the *expression* to use `smallest`, thereby introducing the potentially unwanted side-effect of mutating the input parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are comparing with args[0]. You should compare with the the smaller, so that if there is something smaller than the smaller it will be the new smaller :)

this should work:

```
public static int findSmallestInt(int[] args) {
    int smallest = args[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < args.length; ++i) {
        if (args[i] < smallest ) {
            smallest = args[i];
        }
    }
    return smallest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have told you why the first bit of code doesn't work and offered a lot of alternatives, but allow me to break down exactly where your code breaks. I feel this will be helpful in avoiding similar mistakes.

Here is your original code:

```
public class SmallestIntegerFinder {
    public int findSmallestInt(int[] args){
        int smallest = args[0];
        for(int i=1; i < args.length; ++i){
            if(args[i] < args[0]){
                smallest = args[i];
            }
        }
        return smallest;
     }
 }
```

And here is your input:
`{78,56,232,12,11,43}`

Your original code works perfectly fine up to a certain point, but it's ultimately the comparison `args[i] < args[0]` that causes your code to break.

As your code loops through the array, at some point `smallest` contains the correct value, `11`. But since `11` is not the last element in your array, the code does one more comparison for `43`. Since your comparison is always with `args[0] = 56`, your code checks if `43` is less than `56`, and since it is, overwrites `smallest` with `43`, causing you to get the wrong value.

Changing the comparison to `args[i] < smallest` avoids this problem, because the last iteration of your loop will now check if `43` is less than `11`. Since it is not, your function returns the correct value, `11`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a simpler solution to this:

```
final List<Integer> myList = Arrays.asList(78,56,232,12,11,43);
int smallest = myList.stream()
      .sorted()
      .findFirst()
      .get();
System.out.println("Smallest number is "+smallest);
```

Comment: Define *simpler*. Sorting is more expensive than a linear traversal through the array.

Comment: Simpler means more readable and fewer lines of code than using boilerplate for loops. Unless you're running the program over a huge list on a computer from the 1980s there's no significant performance difference.

Comment: You could still use `IntStream.of(array).min().getAsInt()` like other answers have pointed out, instead of sorting the array, which is a `log(size(array))` factor more expensive.

Comment: I agree, that is better. Anything is better than using C-style code ;)